# fstream won't print to file

Tags: c++, g++, fstream, flush

The following code will print something to a file

```
    std::fstream fout ("D_addr.txt", std::fstream::app);
    fout <<  pkt->Addr() << std::endl;
    flush(fout);
    fout.close();
```

While debugging, I watched `pkt->Addr()` and it has some values. The `fout` line is passed without problem. Also the file `D_addr.txt` is created. However after closing the file, the file size is zero! nothing has been written to it.

Where is the problem?

Comment: What is the return type of pkt->Addr() ?

Comment: it is `typedef uint64_t Addr;`

Comment: Try to check the stream state. The constructor sets `failbit` if the file could not be opened. You can check if the stream is ready for I/O operations with `fstream::good`

Comment: @ChristianAmmer You don't use `fstream::good`.  After opening, it's usual to use `fstream::is_open`, but the general test after each operation (or sequence of operations) is `ios_base::fail`, or the overloaded operators which make the stream act like a `bool`.  And you check _after_ the operation, not before.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Usually I use the overloaded operators and write e.g. `if (fout) {...` but why is it not so good to use `good` to test if stream is ready – I thought it checks all error flags?

Comment: @ChristianAmmer: Yes, it checks if any of the stream's state flags are set (badbit, eofbit or failbit)

Comment: @ChristianAmmer Exactly.  It checks _all_ of the iostate bits.  Even though one (`eofbit`) is irrelevant, and may be set or not.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I understand what you mean, but can it really be, that `eofbit` is undetermined at output file streams? I don't think so, I would guess it's always unset -- although I haven't found a reference neither for the undetermined nor for the unset claim -- and nothing is wrong checking if the stream is ready for I/O operations with `fstream::good`.

Comment: @ChristianAmmer `eofbit` may or may not be set after a successful input, depending on the type being input, and the contents of the stream.  If there are any characters following the type being input, of course, it will not be set, but if this is not the case, it will be set if reading the type requires look-ahead (to know when it ends), and will not be set otherwise.  For all intents and purposes, it's simplest to consider it unspecified.  As for checking before reading: `!fin.good()` means that the read will fail, but `fin.good()` doesn't mean that it will succeed, so why bother?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not your actual code I guess and if it is I would start with that `Addr()` function of yours.

Note that [fstream::close](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/close/) *"closes the file currently associated with the object, disassociating it from the stream. Any pending output sequence is written to the physical file."* `flush(fout);` can be omitted.

You should also specify `std::fstream::out` flag. *"If the function is called with any value in that parameter the default mode is overridden, not combined."* So instead of  `std::fstream::app` you should pass `std::fstream::app | std::fstream::out`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering if you're not using the wrong class.  If you want to write to a file, use `std::ofstream`, and not `std::fstream`.  In particular, the constructor of `std::ofstream` forces the `ios_base::out` bit when calling `rdbuf()->open`; the constructor of `std::fstream` doesn't (so you're opening the file with neither read nor write access).

And you probably want to check the error status: did the open succeed, and after the close (or the flush), did all of the writes succeed.  The usual way of doing this is just:

```
if ( fout ) {
    //  All OK...
}

if ( !fout ) {
    //  Something went wrong.
}
```

After the open (the constructor), you can use `fout.is_open()`, which has the advantage of being a little bit more explicit with regards to what you are checking for.

Comment: *"If the constructor is not successful in opening the file, the object is still created although no file is associated to the stream buffer and the stream's failbit is set."* - He says that file `D_addr.txt` is created, it's just empty. If constructor fails, this file wouldn't be created I guess.

Comment: @LihO Perhaps.  I'm not sure that the standard guarantees atomicity for open (although I would expect it of a good implementation).  And the standard really doesn't say much about what should happen if you request neither read nor write access.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `flush()` and `fout.close()` do not make any harm, but are not needed here, because when `fout` gets destroyed the file will be closed (and flushed) as part of `fstream` destructor.

Second, you should use an `ofstream` or alternatively add the flag `std::ios::out` to the `openmode` parameter.

Try something along the lines of:

```
{
  uint64_t x = 42;
  std::fstream of("test.txt", std::ios::app);
  of << x << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Note, that `fout.close();` could be useful if he calls some function that would lead to programs termination right after writing into `fout`...

Comment: Sure. Completely agree that in many cases `fout.close` can be useful in some circumstances.